# Has Dalai Lama achieved any practical improvements for the people of Tibet?

Tags: tibet

The Dalai Lama is a famous international speaker who is known for his work in promoting the cultural independence of Tibet and the human rights of his people. However it seems that [China has been successful](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18619/how-close-is-china-to-completing-the-cultural-genocide-of-tibet-as-alleged-by) in eradicating the Tibet culture regardless of his work or what international human rights organizations think.

Did Dalai Lama's political work actually manage to affect the people of Tibet after all these years?

Comment: He's probably brought awareness of the people of Tibet to the outside world.

Comment: @MichaelRosen what how did this affect the people of Tibet?

Comment: I see the way of looking at is not "How well treated are the Tibetans right now?", but "How much better/worse off would they be if there wasn't such a PR campaign?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Michael's comment, he has brought awareness to the people of Tibet to the outside world. This has affected the people of Tibet in that they survive as a culture today to a much greater extent than other culture groups that China is doing its best to eradicate through cultural assimilation.

For instance, there were international headlines when reports emerged that China was destroying Larung Gar in 2016. There were a few calls by the Tibetan government in exile (which used to be a theocracy with the Dalai Lama at its helm) for a UN resolution, and an [official condemnation](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/20161208IPR55163/human-rights-buddhism-in-tibet-rohingya-in-myanmar-mass-graves-in-iraq) got voted by the EU Parliament.

Contrast this with e.g. the [Uyghurs](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-22278037), which are a group of Turkic Muslims in the province of Xinjiang ("New Frontier") that are getting culturally assimilated at gun point. There's little to no international public awareness of their situation.